# Adding Masonry to Angular without JQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sass

I am trying to get `Masonry` working as an Angular directive, which is in part documented online, although I am having the following issues on the following code:

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="GridCtrl" class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="masonry">
        <div ng-repeat="item in gridItems" ng-class="item.class">
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <img ng-src="{{item.image}}"/>
            <br>
            <button ng-repeat="button in item.buttons">{{button.text}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular directive code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp').directive('masonry', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.masonry({ itemSelector: '.masonry-item', columnWidth: $parse(attrs.masonry)(scope) });
        }
    };        
});

angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp').directive('masonryItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.imagesLoaded(function () {
               elem.parents('.masonry').masonry('reload');
            });
        }
    };        
});
```

SCSS code:

```
.grid-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 40%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    .masonry {
        position: absolute;
        width: 2600px;
        max-height: 1080px;
        .masonry-item,
        .poster {
            float: left;
            width: 465px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 12px 12px 0 0;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 3px rgba(55,55,55,0.25);
        }
        .masonry-item {
            background: #fafafa;
            height: 295px;
            h3 {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 28px;
                color: #3D444A;
                display: block;
            }
            img {
                display: block;
                padding: 50px 0 10px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        }
        .poster {
            height: 631px;
            background: #000;
            position: relative;
            h3 {
                color: #fff;
                font-family: 'adineuebold';
                font-size: 68px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 410px;
                left: 20px;
                z-index: 2;
            }
            img {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            button {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
                left: 20px;
                top: 590px;
            }
        }
        button {
            padding: 12px 15px;
            font-size: 15px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            font-family: 'adihausregular';
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border: none;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,134,202,1) 0%,rgba(3,75,146,1) 100%);
            &:after {
                content: "";
                background: url('img/sprite.png') no-repeat -156px -9px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                margin-left: 30px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then also, crucially, how my scripts are layered in my index file:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/masonry.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
```

I keep getting an error in the console which would suggest, I am not defining the masonry somewhere correctly:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
```

Then also:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

I would like to avoid using JQuery, possibly, as there is a newer Masonry available that doesn't use it.

Comment: Have you tried loading `masonry.js` before `app.js`? (Putting its `<script>` tag before `app.js`'s in the file)

Comment: Tried that, then it can't define the actual 'app' module.

Comment: The rabbit hole goes pretty deep mate - I ran into this problem myself recently. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504151/masonry-with-angularjs

Comment: That is what I started with and could never get the directive working in my app! A deep hole, indeed!

Comment: If you can see if this is replicating any of the errors you experience, please let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3154/

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6191419

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after a serious hack/play, I have a solution for this: Where AngularJS is creating the view elements on the fly, there are many opportunities for error if the the 'ng-repeat' loads slower than the creation of masonry elements. I am sure there are more Angular style responses to this, but this allows for clean mark up and less Javascript needing to be written to achieve what is needed. Just add this code as a directive, add your child selector and then add 'masonry' to the parent div of the grid in your view:

```
'use strict';

app.directive('masonry', function ($parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {   
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".masonry").masonry({
                    itemSelector : ".masonry-item"
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };        
});
```

Comment: Still getting a `Cannot call method 'create' of undefined` from masonry when trying this. Can you give a little more code on how you implemented this in your view?

Comment: What order are your scripts in your index.html file? I will dig out my code for you.

Comment: setTimeout, really? $(".masonry"), seriously?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not actually applying the directive within your html.

```
<div ng-controller="GridCtrl" class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="masonry" masonry>
        <div ng-repeat="item in gridItems" ng-class="item.class" masonry-item>
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <img ng-src="{{item.image}}"/>
            <br>
            <button ng-repeat="button in item.buttons">{{button.text}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It took me a while to make isotope work in my app, let me know if this helps and if the error you are receiving changes.

Also try and add the column width statically inside your directive for now and see what happens. The error TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'
might relate to attrs.masonry:

```
angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp').directive('masonry', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.masonry({ itemSelector: '.masonry-item', columnWidth: 200 });
        }
    };        
});

angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp').directive('masonryItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.imagesLoaded(function () {
               elem.parents('.masonry').masonry('reload');
            });
        }
    };        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assumed I wouldn't have to apply the directive to the HTML as it was linked to the class. I have added the method you suggested and it throws up further errors. I think I am not declaring the directive correctly in the app: Other than a script tag in the index.html file, the directive code and the reference in the controller HTML am I missing something?

Comment: which other errors are you getting? Directives are applied within the html tag you want to use them with. That is the point of directives. the variable element within the directive then contains a reference to that html element

Comment: These ones: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded' | TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Comment: have you included the jquery imagesloaded plugin? I would include it before masonry.js
https://raw.github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/master/imagesloaded.js also I think you might have to call images loaded like this, but I might be wrong: elem.find("img").imagesLoaded(.....)

Comment: I installed all of the dependencies through Bower, using the version of Masonry that doesn't require JQuery. As I am trying to avoid doing that. Though I have done what you said, and I still get the same errors.

Comment: imagesloaded is a jquery plugin though so if you want to use it you need to include jquery. If you don't want to use the plugin and implement your own images loaded thing then you can do that instead. For now try and remove the images loaded in in your masonryItem directive like this ------- link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { elem.parents('.masonry').masonry('reload');} -------- you will however have the problem that the masonry will relad before the images have loaded and that will cause sizing problems in masonry

Comment: if you can create a jsfiddle it'll be easier to see what's going wrong

Comment: Cool, all added, though still get these errors: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined. Also, isn't 'parents()' a JQuery method? Can I just use 'parent()' in plain Javascript?

Comment: I'll make a fiddle now. Cheers!

Comment: btw... looking at your includes you don't seem to include masonry anywhere (you only include the masonry directives file, but you also need to include the masonry library

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/masonry.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>

Comment: Ah, yeah, AngularJS chucks those in the components directory, which is defined slightly higher up the list in my index.html: <script src="components/masonry/masonry.js"></script>

Comment: Didn't realise it was such a pain to set up these in JSFiddle! Made a start, will finish it off as soon as I can get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/nd6GS/

Comment: Oki, so I fixed it for you, however couldn't make it work without jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz5uT/4/ SOZ! Perhaps someone else will come up with a better solution that doesn't need jquery - with this solution you could also use the imagesloaded plugin though

Comment: Thanks. Now time to integrate that in to my build!

Comment: Just one further question about the fiddle: If I remove the static 'first item', it breaks the fiddle. Do you know what causes that?

Comment: give this a go: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz5uT/14/ Masonry seems to expect at least one element within container. However at the time when masonry is instatiated this is not the case as repeat runs after. Therefore I would init masonry within the masonry-item directive.

Comment: I decided not to implement that approach. Not because it doesn't work, but because it seemed a more code heavy way of doing it. I used the method above that I posted, wrapping the code that is provided by Masonry.js in a setTimeout function.

Comment: I decided to use the $timeout way of doing things too. But I wonder what the advantages/disadvantages of putting the directive's priority lower than the ng-repeat, so that it can wait for the repeat to finish.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to make Masonry refire when you add items to an ng-repeat? Not working for me!